# Where is data updated in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, width, wait

I am creating a tab page entirley programatically from a button press in the root page of a tabbed control. At present all the page initialisation takes place in the button click method. After all the instantiation, data capture from file and so on, I finally want to adjust the column widths in the data grid view, so that all the row data appears without having to have horizontal scroll bars. With the help of all your contributors I have managed to get it all working but the last step. Running at full speed it appears the `DataGridView` is accessed before the data load from the table is complete as it fails with an exception because the count derived from `RegistersGrid.ColumnCount` (local variable l) is  zero. It all works fine if I step through the code. I am assuming that I need to put a Mutex of some form to wait for the transfer to complete, but I can't work out where that is taking place in order to reset the flag! If someone can point me in the right direction or if there is better more structured way to approach this I would deeply appreciate the help :-)

I have included all the code in the method just in case, I am afraid I date back a long way so if this looks like the awkward child of assembler,pascal and c with a little c# thrown in, my apologies....it's my age :-)

```
private void AddModuleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ModuleID = null;
    string ModuleTypeFileNumber = null;
    string ModuleType = null;
    int TabID = 0;

    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt";
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
        {
            string newline;
            
            if ((newline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] values = newline.Split((char)9);
                ModuleTypeFileNumber = values[1];
            }
            
            if ((newline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] values = newline.Split();
                ModuleID = values[0];
                ModuleType = values[1];
            }
            
            bool AbsorbLines = true;
            
            while (AbsorbLines && ((newline = reader.ReadLine()) != null))
            {
                string[] values = newline.Split();
                if (values[0] == "Readings") AbsorbLines = false;
            }
            
            string[] columnnames = { "Summary", "access", "register", "Module & Name", "Value", "unit", "type", "Res" };
            string[] columntypes = { "System.Boolean", "System.String", "System.Int32", "System.String", "System.Int32", "System.String", "System.String", "System.String" };
            int[] columnwidth = { 1,2,3,35,10,5,5,5 };
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            
            for(int i =0; i < columnnames.Length; i++)
            {
                DataColumn colString = new DataColumn(columnnames[i]);
                colString.DataType = System.Type.GetType(columntypes[i]);
                dt.Columns.Add(colString);
            }
            
            while (ImportTable("Controls", reader.ReadLine(), dt, "RO")) { }    // Import the "readings" section
            
            while (ImportTable("Status bits", reader.ReadLine(), dt, "RW")) { } // Import the "controls" section
            
            reader.Close();

            registerTables.Add(ModuleID, dt);

            // create a new tab page
            TabPage page = new TabPage(ModuleID);
            InterbusRegisters.TabPages.Add(page);
            
            // 
            // tabPage1
            // 
            Button ResizeButton = new Button();
            Button RemoveButton = new Button();
            Label VersionLabel = new Label();
            Label SerialNolabel = new Label();
            TextBox VersionNoTB = new TextBox();
            TextBox SerialNoTB = new TextBox();
            DataGridView RegistersGrid = new DataGridView();

            //
            // Set the properties of the DataGrid.
            //
            RegistersGrid.AccessibleName = ModuleID + "Grid";
            RegistersGrid.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3,29);
            RegistersGrid.Width = page.Width - 6;
            RegistersGrid.Height = page.Height - 29;
            RegistersGrid.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left);
            RegistersGrid.DataSource = dt;
            RegistersGrid.Dock = (DockStyle)2;
            // 
            // RemoveButtonRegistersGrid
            // 
            RemoveButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            RemoveButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 4);
            RemoveButton.Name = "RemoveButton";
            RemoveButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 25);
            RemoveButton.TabIndex = 0;
            RemoveButton.Text = "Remove";
            RemoveButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            RemoveButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.RemoveButton_Click);
            // 
            // ResizeButton
            // 
            ResizeButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;
            ResizeButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(81, 4);
            ResizeButton.Name = "ResizeButton";
            ResizeButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 25);
            ResizeButton.TabIndex = 6;
            ResizeButton.Text = "Resize";
            ResizeButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            ResizeButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ResizeButton_Click);
            // 
            // SerialNolabel
            // 
            SerialNolabel.AutoSize = true;
            SerialNolabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(159, 10);
            SerialNolabel.Name = "SerialNolabel";
            SerialNolabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 13);
            SerialNolabel.TabIndex = 4;
            SerialNolabel.Text = "Serial No:";
            // 
            // SerialNoTB
            // 
            SerialNoTB.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(215, 7);
            SerialNoTB.Name = "SerialNoTB";
            SerialNoTB.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            SerialNoTB.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // VersionLabel
            // 
            VersionLabel.AutoSize = true;
            VersionLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(318, 10);
            VersionLabel.Name = "VersionLabel";
            VersionLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 13);
            VersionLabel.TabIndex = 5;
            VersionLabel.Text = "Version:";
            // 
            // VersionTB
            // 
            VersionNoTB.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(366, 7);
            VersionNoTB.Name = "VersionTB";
            VersionNoTB.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            VersionNoTB.TabIndex = 2;

            page.Controls.Add(ResizeButton);
            page.Controls.Add(RemoveButton);
            page.Controls.Add(VersionLabel);
            page.Controls.Add(VersionNoTB);
            page.Controls.Add(SerialNolabel);
            page.Controls.Add(SerialNoTB);
            page.Controls.Add(RegistersGrid);
            page.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
            page.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(716, 554);
            page.TabIndex = 1;
            page.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            page.Update(); // the following code fails 

            int k = dt.Columns.Count;
            int l = RegistersGrid.ColumnCount;

            for (int j = 0; j <= RegistersGrid.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
                RegistersGrid.Columns[j].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
                
            RegistersGrid.Columns[3].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

            //datagrid has calculated it's widths so we can store them
            for (int i = 0; i <= RegistersGrid.ColumnCount - 1; i++)
            {
                int colw = RegistersGrid.Columns[i].Width; //store autosized widths
                RegistersGrid.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None; //remove autosizing
                RegistersGrid.Columns[i].Width = colw; //set width to calculated by autosize
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hello Dave, Welcome to SO. In order to test the posted code, it should be “complete” for your benefit and others who attempt to help. It is important that we are both on the same page. I am not fully understanding what exactly the problem is, however, the posted code is missing some important parts, that are needed to reproduce the issue you are having. One issue, what is `registerTables`? In addition, it is unclear what the two `while` loops are doing and what the `ImportTable` method is doing. This is not clear and needs clarification.

Comment: Another problem, is the code is opening a text file. The info in this text file is used and appears to be structured in a particular way. No one is going to “guess” and re-create this file and test it on your code. Anytime, the code reads a file and uses it in the posted code, it is expected that you supply at least a test version of the file that re-creates the issue you are having. When you post code to your question that is missing parts and is incomplete, you are doing yourself a disservice since most users will simply move on to another question. This obviously is not going to help YOU.

Comment: If you can add the needed info described above, this will help anyone trying to re-produce the problem. Otherwise, the question may get down voted or worse, be closed as it is incomplete. Since it appears you are fairly new to SO, the following links may help you in getting the help you asked for. I suggest you peruse the SO [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) section as it shows how SO works. The [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful. Good Luck.

Comment: OK, Thanks guys. This is part of a much bigger app. So I will try to create a small version to demonstrate the problem, and post that. It will probably take a day or two tough I am afraid.................

Comment: Dave I certainly can sympathize with having to create an MRE. However, there are benefits.

Comment: Creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is a “process” that should be in every coder’s toolbox, you would be surprised how often this simple process will “reveal” the problem you are having. As a bonus, IF, after creating the MRE, the problem still persists, then you will have the code needed to post on “SO” such that others can simply copy/paste the code to reproduce the same problem. Posting incomplete code only forces others to “guess” and speculate. And, worse for you, they will simply move to another question.

Comment: In the mean time to answer the question the while loops just import, and parse a text file, filling in dt (the data table) as it goes.
My whole problem is it that I am not clear when the data is actually transferred to the grid, It must be before the page is displayed (or stepping through would not work ok) but it is clearly happening in another thread or it would work every time!

Comment: The data is getting loaded into the grid with the line… `RegistersGrid.DataSource = dt;`… unless your code specifically started a background worker or another thread, the above command will execute using the main thread. So, I seriously doubt if it is a threading issue unless you are doing this. Since the grid is on a tab page, is “that” tab page “active” when the above line of code is executed? It should not matter, however, just a guess.